# Поле ввода с пробелом для range slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Пытаюсь сделать поле ввода для range slider jquery ui с пробелом:

```js
$('.slider-element').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      container = $this.closest('.slider'),
      min = parseInt($this.data('min')),
      max = parseInt($this.data('max')),
      from = container.find('.from'),
      to = container.find('.to');

  console.log(parseInt(from.val()));

  from.change(function() {


    var value1 = from.val(),
        value2 = to.val();

    if(parseInt(value1) > parseInt(value2)){
      value1 = value2;
      from.val(value1);
    }

    $this.slider('values', 0, from.val()).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ");

    console.log();
  });

  to.change(function() {
    var value1 = from.val(),
        value2 = to.val();

    if(parseInt(value1) > parseInt(value2)){
      value2 = value1;
      to.val(value2);
    }

    $this.slider('values', 1, to.val());
  });

  $this.slider({
    range: true,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    step: 83,
    values: [min, max],
    slide: function(event, ui) { // При каждом перемещении
      var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
      from.val(ui.values[0]);
      to.val(ui.values[1]);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) { // В конце перетаскивания    
      console.log('change'); 
    },
    create: function() { // При создании виджета
      var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
      from.val(values[0]);
      to.val(values[1]);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) { // При завершении перетаскивания

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-display">
   <input type="text" name="slider" class="input from" >
    <input type="text" name="slider" class="input to">     
  </div>
  <div class="slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="1000"></div>
</div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
 <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Использую `.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ")`, но видимо не правильно.

Не пойму что не так в коде, как осуществить такой формат ввода `12 345`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решила так:

```js
$('.slider-element').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      container = $this.closest('.slider'),
      min = parseInt($this.data('min')),
      max = parseInt($this.data('max')),
      from = container.find('.from'),
      to = container.find('.to');


  from.change(function() {    

    var value1 = from.val(),
        value2 = to.val(),
        value1new = value1.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 "),
        value2new = value1.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ");

    if(parseInt(value1) > parseInt(value2)){
      value1 = value2;
      from.val(value1);
    }

    $this.slider('values', 0, from.val(value1new));

    console.log();
  });

  to.change(function() {
    var value1 = from.val(),
        value2 = to.val();

    if(parseInt(value1) > parseInt(value2)){
      value2 = value1;
      to.val(value2);
    }

    $this.slider('values', 1, to.val());
  });

  $this.slider({
    range: true,
    min: min,
    max: max,
    step: 83,
    values: [min, max],
    slide: function(event, ui) { // При каждом перемещении
      var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
      from.val(ui.values[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 "));
      to.val(ui.values[1].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 "));
    },
    change: function(event, ui) { // В конце перетаскивания    
      console.log('change'); 
    },
    create: function() { // При создании виджета
      var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
      from.val(values[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 "));
      to.val(values[1].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1 "));
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) { // При завершении перетаскивания

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="slider">
   <div class="slider-display">
     <input type="text" name="slider" class="input from" >
     <input type="text" name="slider" class="input to">     
     
   </div>
   
   <div class="slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="1000"></div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
 <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```